# jQuery UI Combobox Widget not working with click() event?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

How come when I write a click() event where the input field (created by the jquery ui combobox widget) is in scope of the selector the event never fires?

I have a form that has a validation which highlights the entire parent <div> of that form field using the css class 'reqFieldGroupEmpty' when the end-user doesn't fill it out correctly.

When a user clicks inside the missed required field I have a click() event remove that class of that form field's parent

```
$('input, textarea, select').click(function () { $('div').removeClass('reqFieldGroupEmpty') });
```

However, as I mentioned at the start, the combobox-created  isn't triggering the click(), thus not removing the class.

What am I missing?

Thank you for helping!

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle.net to see what its happening?
if you use chrome or firefox with firebug, yo could try to set a breakpoint to see if its being executed

Comment: I've been using firebug with a console.log("I've been clicked") message with the click() event function and it does get executed with all of the other inputs in the jQuery selector, just not the ones created by the widget? I've even tried going right to the heart of that input using    $('input[role="textbox"].ui-autocomplete-input').click(function () { console.log("I've been clicked") });  and that doesn't work either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Post answered by JakeCigar via jQuery Forum:
http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-ui-combobox-widget-not-working-with-click-event#14737000003343231

> click is only finding the elements that exist when you set it up.
>   Use the deferred form of .on() – jQuery API

```
$('body').on('click’, 'input, textarea, select' , function () { $('div').removeClass('reqFieldGroupEmpty') });
```

> JΛ̊KE"

Answer (score 0):

try binding to the focus() event instead of click...

Comment: great idea, no-go though.  It's almost like since the input element was created by the widget it's not getting any of the event handler's bound to it?  Is there a way to forcibly bind events to elements if they were created from a script?  I should mention I haven't had any luck with live() or on() but I could be implementing them incorrectly.  I'm just jQuery 1.7. Thoughts?

Comment: really need to see the HTML & JavaScript you're using to be able to help more...  can you create a JSFiddle for it?

Answer (score 0):

I think I can reproduce what wizzy was seeing. This code works fine inside a `$(function(){...});`:

```
$('<button>', {text: 'Go'}).appendTo($('body')).on('click', function() {
    console.log('clicked');
});
```

But inside a widget the clicked never gets logged. Example:

```
_init: function() {
    $('<button>', {text: 'Go'}).appendTo(this.element).on('click', function() {
        console.log('clicked');
    });
}
```

The button is appended but no click event seems to be fired.

http://jsfiddle.net/cawoodm/cww3c/

Comment: OK, in my case the problem is that I am calling the jQuery UI .button() function on my element after I bind the events (see the jsfiddle link). This seems to have the effect of removing existing bindings.